# `Error in 1:nrow(A) : argument of length 0` using function kmodes of Package ‘klaR’

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `A`, from which I try to calculate a second matrix `B`, in this way:

```
B<-t(sapply(1:nrow(A), function(x) {
 rowSums((t(t(A)-A[x,])!=0))
}))
```

As a result of this, I obtained the following error

```
Error in 1:nrow(A) : argument of length 0
```

What does that mean?

**EDIT:** Matrix A derives from the following operation:

```
for(i in 1:n){
 A <- matrix(unlist(out[i]), ncol = 8, byrow = FALSE)
}
```

where

```
data.to.cluster <- read.csv('dataset.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';') 
cluster.results <-kmodes(data.to.cluster[,2:8], n, iter.max = 100, weighted = FALSE ) 
v <- as.matrix(unlist(cluster.results[1]))
df1<-data.to.cluster
out <- split(df1, v)
```

and `n` is the number of modes.

Comment: Are you sure `A` is a matrix? You get that error when when you run `1:NULL`, so it seems likely `nrow(A)` is returning `NULL` which would happen if `A` is an atomic vector.

Comment: I agree, i created a matrix doing `A<-matrix(1:9,3,3)` and it works fine

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the error, and now I' edited my post.